# Intent ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE - how to delete duplicated thumbnail?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-camera-intent

After taking a photo by using intent `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` with given location to save photo on some devices (my test device is Sony Ericsson Mt11i with android 2.3) default camera app is saving a duplicate image in camera photos folder.

So my app checks if the photo is duplicated and deletes it. But the camera app also saving the thumbnail for taken photo, so i'm deleting it too, but even after I delete this thumbnail there is somewhere still information about this thumbnail, and in device's gallery app image is still present with default image. If I check details of this image there is still information of this photo (date,location). These are my methods for handling duplicated photo:

```
public static void handleTakenPicture(Context context, int lastId, File tempFile) {
    /*
     * Checking for duplicate images
     * This is necessary because some camera implementation not only save where you want them to save but also in their default location.
     */
    if (lastId == 0)
        return;
    final String[] projection = {MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA, MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATE_TAKEN,
            MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.SIZE, MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns._ID};
    final String imageOrderBy = MediaStore.Images.Media._ID + " DESC";
    final String imageWhere = MediaStore.Images.Media._ID + ">?";
    final String[] imageArguments = {Integer.toString(lastId)};
    Cursor imageCursor = context.getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, projection, imageWhere, imageArguments,
            imageOrderBy);
   // List<File> cameraTakenMediaFiles = new ArrayList<File>();
    File gFile = null;
    if (imageCursor.getCount() > 0) {
       // while( imageCursor.moveToNext() ) {
        imageCursor.moveToFirst();
            // int id =
            // imageCursor.getInt(imageCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media._ID));
            String path = imageCursor.getString(imageCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA));
            gFile = new File(path);
            // Long takenTimeStamp =
            // imageCursor.getLong(imageCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_TAKEN));
            // Long size =
            // imageCursor.getLong(imageCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.SIZE));
           // cameraTakenMediaFiles.add(new File(path));
        //}
    }

    imageCursor.close();


    //File imageFile = new File(imageFilePath);


    if (!tempFile.exists() && gFile != null) {
        // was not saved where I wanted, but the camera saved one in the media folder
        // try to copy over the one saved by the camera and then delete
        try {
            Prefsy.copyFile(gFile, tempFile);
            gFile.delete();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    if(gFile != null)
        {
        gFile.delete();
        try { // DELETING THUMBNAIL
            Cursor th = context.getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, new String[] {MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA},
                    MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.IMAGE_ID + " = ?", new String[] {"" + lastId}, MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails._ID + " DESC");

            L(th.getCount()+"");

            if (th.getCount() > 0)
            {
                th.moveToFirst();
                L(th.getString(0));
                L(new File(th.getString(0)).delete()+"");
                L(context.getContentResolver().delete(MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                        MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.IMAGE_ID + " = ?", new String[] {"" + lastId})+"");
            }
            th.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }

        }
    /*for( File cameraTakenFile : cameraTakenMediaFiles ) {
        // delete the one duplicated
        cameraTakenFile.delete();
    }*/
}

public static int getLastImageId(Context context){
    final String[] imageColumns = { MediaStore.Images.Media._ID };
    final String imageOrderBy = MediaStore.Images.Media._ID+" DESC";
    final String imageWhere = null;
    final String[] imageArguments = null;
    Cursor imageCursor = context.getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, imageColumns, imageWhere, imageArguments, imageOrderBy);
    if(imageCursor.moveToFirst()){
        int id = imageCursor.getInt(imageCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media._ID));
        imageCursor.close();
        return id;
    }else{
        return 0;
    }
}
```

L() is Log method